# The connection manager will not acquire a connection because the connection manager OfflineMode property is set to TRUE

Tags: ssis

When I open my existing SSIS project in design view I get the following error:

```
The connection manager will not acquire a connection because the connection manager OfflineMode property is set to TRUE
```

Meanwhile the OfflineMode is set to false. Can anyone tell me why am I getting this error?

DelayValidation property of the connection is set to false and if I set it to true, the error goes away. But I just wanted to figure out why is this happening. I am not setting connection dynamically and last time I used the project, there were no errors and it ran while DelayValidation was set to false. What has changed?

Comment: Since SQL Server 2012 you can set the OfflineMode on both the connection manager and the package levels.  Perhaps the option is set for the entire package?

Comment: nope, I already checked

Comment: Whenever Connection manager could not connect to database, you're connection status for that particular connection will change to offline, are you sure that your connection is available?

Comment: yes, it is. I can access the database from Management Studio

Answer (score 43):

Right-click on the Connection Managers area of SSIS Designer and then look at the "Work Offline" option to ensure it is not checked. If it is checked, uncheck it.

[image: Screenshot of contextual menu of the Connection Managers window showing the "Work Offline" option as checked]

or[image]

You may have to do this for each connection manager.

Comment: Hm it checked that box because I first opened the project without being in the correct VPN, so it couldn't connect at first

Comment: First I was receiving the error even work offline was not selected. Selecting work offline and de-selecting work offline enabled the run to succeed.

Answer (score 4):

This didn't work for me because I was using a connection string expressions.  Clearing the 'work offline' check would temporarily appear to work, but then it would suddenly recheck.  This was frustrating to say the least.

Once I edited the connection string to place the provider in the correct place (see image for what worked for me) then it stopped toggling the 'offline' mode on because it could connect to the DB.
[image]

Comment: Also update your local variables in the variables windows before turning off offline mode

Answer (score 1):

Please create a variable for data source of the connection manager and apply to the  connectionString Expression.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can test your connection and it works but you get this error whenever you try to access anything from the DB.

Actually you've probably just accidently selected the offline mode.

1. Go to the SSIS menu option.
2. Find the selection "Work Offline"
3. Unselect it and you should be good.

I accidentally hit this every once in a while when accessing the variables menu... very frustrating.

Comment: For example, can happen if you open the solution while not in the proper VPN - and since it can't connect the DB it switches it might switch it to "Work Offline"

Comment: Where is the "SSIS Menu Option"? I don't see such an menu option in Visual Studio anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow that got turned on for me and in 2019 it's in

Extensions>SSIS>Work Offline

Just uncheck it

Answer (score 0):

Please check package parameterize properties, right click over your package area and select Parameterize item from the Menu, then set property to OfflineMode and see if it set to any existing parameter or not. if it's the case, then the parameter value is changing to True at run-time. try to find the location where this Parameter is changing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was due to the provider in the Connection String. So what I did was create a new connection to the server and database, and check which provider were used in the new connection. Then change the provider in the old connection (it is assigned by expession). It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same concern, and the above information was helpful. I was able to overcome the concern by placing a default value in my expressions 'Connection String' variable.

[image: Screenshot of my default value]

Answer (score -1):

Had this issue, just ignore the error it gives you and try running it anyways. If you were offline from the network recently it might show this error but ignore it.