# SSIS Foreach Loop Container OLE DB- Problem with dynamic connection

Tags: ssis, expression, foreach-loop-container

I am setting up a new datawarehouse (Server 1) and need to get data from 3 different databases on the same server (Server 2). Everything works good until until I try to make the connection dynamic.

I have created a Foreach Loop Container FLC including 4 variables

- Servername
- Database
- User
- Pw

In the FLC I have added a data flow task DFT, and in the DFT added a OLE DB Source
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In the OLE DB Source connection properties I have added the the 1 variables as expression.
Directly the connection goes to offline and OLE DB Source gives an error. Error message:

> Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PysJ.png)]: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Test" failed
>   with error code 0xC0014041.  There may be error messages posted before
>   this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call
>   failed.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: OLE DB Source failed
>   validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed
>   validation.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
>
> Error at Package: The connection manager "Test" will not acquire a
>   connection because the connection manager OfflineMode property is
>   TRUE. When the OfflineMode is TRUE, connections cannot be acquired.
>
> (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

Comment: If you are looking to change the provider check the following link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1c8205d3-a047-41eb-839a-c66883a4ba9d/how-to-change-provider-in-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices]=

Comment: The correct provider (SQL Server Native Client 11,0) is selected when I create the connection, but when I make it dynamic it gets destoyed and gives error

Comment: @Mags can you provide some screenshot of the data flow and foreach loop container and the connection expression?

Comment: How are the variables populated?  And is this mapped in the Foreach Loop?

Comment: Anyone out there who can help:)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using the following provider which is not adequate:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers

Instead, select `SQL Server Native Client 11` in the connection manager.

Next step, is to change the Data Flow Task and OLEDB Source `Delay Validation` property to `True` since if the variables defauly values are empty it will throw an error on the package validation phase (once executed)

### Update 1 - ConnectionString property

Instead of assigning expressions to multiple connection manager properties, use the connectionstring expression:

```
"Data Source=" + @[User::SERVER] + ";User ID=" + @[User::USERNAME] + ";Password=" + @[User::PASSWORD] +";Initial Catalog=" + @[User::DATABASE] + ";Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but still the samme error. SQL Server Native Client 11 is in the connection string

Comment: @Mags from the error message you are using `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Driver` even if native client is provided in the connection string

Comment: I have changed to one connection string in the connection properties, but new error message.

Comment: @Mags check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701696/the-connection-manager-will-not-acquire-a-connection-because-the-connection-mana